# Safely concatenate multibyte strings

Tags: php, string, multibyte

I'm looking increasingly into ensuring that PHP apps are multibyte-safe, which mostly involves replacing string manipulation functions with their equivilant mb_* functions.

However string concatenation is giving me pause for thought.

Some character encodings (such as UTF-16 unicode) can include a Byte Order Mark at the beginning.  If you concatenated two UTF16 strings it's possible you'd introduce a BOM into the resulting string at a location other than the beginning.  I suspect that there are other encodings that can also include "header" information such that stitching two strings of the same encoding together would also be problematic.  Is PHP smart enough to discard BOMs etc when doing multibyte string concatenations?  I suspect not because PHP has traditionally only treated strings as a sequence of bytes.  Is there a multibyte-safe equivalent to concatenation?  I've not been able to find anything in the mbstring documentation.

Obviously it would never be safe to concatenate strings that are in different encodings so I'm not worrying about that for now.

Comment: *"Is PHP smart enough"* – no. The solution is, as expected, to trim BOMs off of strings before concatenating them.

Comment: Two years and nine months with no concrete answer, and what about plain UTF-8 multi-byte strings?

Answer (score 0):

> PHP has traditionally only treated strings as a sequence of bytes

It still does.  PHP has no concept of a *character string*, as it exists in other languages.  Therefore, all strings are always byte strings and you will need to manually track which of them are binary strings, which are character strings and which encoding is being used.  An effort to bring Unicode strings to PHP resulted in [PHP 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#PHP_6_and_Unicode), which was abandoned and never released.  But then again, even languages which do have native character strings will not automatically do what you're asking for anyway.

Have a look at the [Unicode FAQ about BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM), some of the information below directly comes from there.

If a byte order mark ends up in the middle of a string, Unicode dictates that it should be interpreted as ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE.  I conclude that this shouldn't usually be an issue, so it's not so terrible to just ignore BOMs.

However, if that bothers you, my recommendation is as follows:

- Try to avoid BOMs altogether and mark the data stream accordingly.  For example, when using HTTP, set the encoding to `UTF-16BE` or `UTF-16LE` using headers.
- Sanitize all inputs used by the application (user input, files loaded, ...) as early as possible, by removing these BOMs and converting the encoding.  You may even want to use the [`Normalizer`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) class.  Use your favorite framework's features if available.
- Use one and only one encoding internally.  Use [`mb_internal_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) to set a default for all `mb_*()` functions.
- When outputting strings, add any desired BOMs back to the strings if you must.  Again, it's preferable to just mark the data stream correctly.

That said, note that concatenating multi-byte strings can cause a multitude of unexpected situations, the BOM in the middle of a string is just one of them.  Issues may also arise when using [bidirectional text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text) where RTL or LTR code points in the first string being concatenated may affect text in the second string.  Further, many issues may also arise when using other string operations, for example using `mb_substr()` on bidirectional text may also produce unexpected results.  Text involving combining diacritical marks may also be problematic.